# Not understanding permissions to write on Amazon EC2 Server

Tags: php, c++, amazon-ec2, file-permissions, user-permissions

I developed a Command Line Tool (CLT) on a Amazon EC2 (Linux) machine. It's OpenCV based, so I can execute my script and being able to write images on the server (by `imwrite(std::string path, cv::Mat image)` ).

I do that exactly from the console and it writes successfully, but when I'm trying to call it from a PHP-script (**apache** user), it is able to get the input file on PHP, moving it to one specific folder but when I execute the Command Line Tool through `exec($execQuery, $output, $return)`, my c++ CLT **doesn't write any image**.

The PHP code is:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                               "/var/www/html/public/saved/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$path = "/var/www/html/public/saved/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$dest = "/var/www/html/public/saved/DEST_" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$execQuery = sprintf("/usr/local/bin/binary_test -source \"%s\" -dest \"%s\"", $path, $dest);

exec($execQuery, $output, $return); // this should execute my binary which writes an image
```

and the `saved` folder has as user: **ec2-user** and www as **group**. I've tried to change it to **apache** but I didn't get any result.

Does anyone have a clue for this?

Thank you very much in advance. Regards.

---

Edit:

The `$return` code is **6**.

---

Edit2:

if I apply "sudo" before the exec command, the **return code is 1**. Otherwise **it's 6**

---

After hours and hours debugging, I'm getting the error on the c++ line where I call the function:

`CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale`, I still can't imagine why.